# Is there a way to determine which django db a pytest test function is currently running against?

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

Is there a way to know which database a test is currently running against from within the test itself?
i.e. I have a test setup like so, and I have two databases configured

```
pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db(databases=["db1", "db2"])

def test_case_1(fixture_stuff):
    print("What db is this running on?")
```

Is there a way for me to add the current db to that print statement?

Answer (score 0):

Which db will be used is determined when calculating the query.

So, "current running db" cannot be determined without query.

This is an example of routing with a read-only(`replica`), write-only(`default`) db.

```
# settings

DATABASES = {
    "default": {...},
    "replica": {...},
}
```

```
# routers

class Router:
    @staticmethod
    def db_for_read(model, **hints):
        conn = transaction.get_connection("default")
        if conn.in_atomic_block:
            return "default"

        return "replica"

    @staticmethod
    def db_for_write(model, **hints):
        return "default"

    @staticmethod
    def allow_relation(obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def allow_migrate(db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return True
```

When you perform SELECT operations, the 'replica' database will be the currently active one; otherwise, the 'default' database will be used.

However, if you only use the default db, you can find connected database with this code.

```
from django.db import connection
print(connection._connections.databases["default"])
```

Comment: Is there no other way?
If I only specify one db in the django_db marker, the test runs once. when I specify two, the test runs twice, I'm assuming once for each db. If that info isn't made available to the test is there maybe a way to ask the test runner which db this case is executing on?